# Explanation of While Loop Using the Logical Operator "not"

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop, logical-operators

Code from "Think Like a Computer Scientist: Python"

```
def find(astring, achar):
ix = 0
found = False
while ix < len(astring) and not found:
    if astring[ix] == achar:
        found = True
    else:
        ix = ix + 1
if found:
    return ix
else:
    return -1
```

I've run this through CodeLens in all variations of location of `not` and original value for `found`, but cannot wrap my head around the way Python handles its conditions in this form. Please point out where my train of thought goes wrong or what I miss:

If `found = False`, then `not found = True` when `found = True`.
The condition is set to `not found` so the loop will iterate. (I set the condition to `found` and it does not iterate. So while loops must only iterate for `True` values). Once `achar` is found in `astring`, `found = True`. What is the logic behind this closing the loop? Where is my misunderstanding of the use of `not`?

Comment: "If found = False, then not found = True when found = True" - what the heck?

Comment: Once `achar` is found in `astring`, you want to stop looking, and thus stop looping, don't you?  So you set `found = True` in order to end the loop.  Is that what you're asking about?

Comment: To user: Where is my logic wrong? Set a variable to True or False. Then use the not operator on it. Isn't the not operator used when a condition is checked for, but you want the opposite?

Comment: jwodder, yes that's what I'm asking about. But specifically I'm asking what is the logic behind stopping when `found = True`, because to me, `not found = True`, so where does the changing of conditions occur? What am I missing about the `not` operator?

Comment: @Tyler_P: I believe user2357112 was reacting to the fact that you wrote "if found = False ... when found = True", which makes no sense.

Comment: Would the proper way to convey that be, if `found = False`, then `not found = True` when `found == True`? Or am I still wrong and that makes no sense to anyone? If so, how do you express `not found` becoming true, or false, for that matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should consider the Not operator as an inverter. The logic table would be:

- A | Not A
- T | F
- F | T

So when Found is False it is actually True and when it is True it is False.

The conditional statement for the while loop works as while True - execute code, while false exit code.

Looking at the conditional, it is an and operation where both operations have to be True to be True, if you look up the and gate truth table you can learn more about it.

Basically, both 'ix < len(astring) and not found' have to be true for the loop to.

Hope this helps

Comment: This is exactly what was needed. Thanks a million for this "aha" moment with the Not operator.